# Activity class does not exist - why?

Tags: android, android-activity, manifest

I could not find the reason why the logcat reports that the Activity class `com.abc.marksix.SugarActivity` does not exist. The Manifest, Logcat, app/build.gradle and project structure are as follows. Could you please help?

### Code:

### Android Manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:name="SugarOrmTestApplication"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.com.abc.marksix"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-xxx/xxx"
     />

    <activity
        android:name="com.abc.marksix.SugarActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

### Logcat:

```
10/28 01:01:47: Launching app
$ adb push C:\Users\xxx\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.abc.marksix
$ adb shell pm install -t -r "/data/local/tmp/com.abc.marksix"
Success
APK installed in 2 s 777 ms
$ adb shell am start -n "com.abc.marksix/com.abc.marksix.SugarActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Error while executing: am start -n "com.abc.marksix/com.abc.marksix.SugarActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.abc.marksix/.SugarActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.abc.marksix/com.abc.marksix.SugarActivity} does not exist.
```

### Project structure:

[image]

### app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abc.marksix"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'

    implementation 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.5'
    implementation 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.adlocus:library:3.5.7@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation files('src/main/java/com/abc/libs/jeval.jar')
    implementation files('src/main/java/com/abc/libs/jscience.jar')
}
```

Comment: What is the value for `applicationId` in your `app/build.gradle` file?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, build.gradle is now added to the question

Comment: Did you try first to uninstall the app from the emulator/device and then run it again?

Comment: tried adb uninstall from device, it cannot find the app anymore

Comment: Your syntax seems different from all the [examples I'm finding on Google](https://medium.com/@xabaras/starting-an-activity-via-adb-47119bdf514f)

Answer (score 1):

On my side, i did using the Android Studio Top Menu :

Files and Re-Import Gradle Project 
Build and Clean Project
Build and Make Project
Run App (after exiting all Virtual Devices)

and it worked fine after tested all solutions found in StackOverFlow

Hope it will be helpfull for you

Note that the Re-Import Gradle Project can be enough =) because it seems to do by itself the rest

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine and everything is correct. You just need to do is,

**First, run your application from IDE and let it install.

Second,
Try uninstalling the application from the device settings, not from launcher or adb.**
Hope it works!

Comment: Yes, i tried running the application from IDE and let it install. It said it can be installed sucessfuly, but the app just cannot be opened, and the logcat is as above. Without running from IDE, I have nothing to uninstall however. Could you please advise?

Comment: Have you disabled instant run? How about trying with Emulator(AVD)? Note : After uninstalling the app from your phone, restart your phone.